# Trouble retrying on interrupted system call

Tags: python

I have recently run into an issue at work where we are having intermittent problems with an internal website not loading due to an interrupted system call. We are using urllib2 to access the website. I can't share the exact code, but here is basically how we do it:

```
payload = {'userName': user_name,
           'emailAddress': email_address,
           'password': password}
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': token}
values = json.dumps(payload)
req = urllib2.Request(url, values, headers)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=30)
    break
except IOError, e:
    if e.errno != errno.EINTR:
        print e.errno
    raise
```

We log the errono and the raised exception. The exception is:

```
IOError: <urlopen error [Errno 4] Interrupted system call>
```

And the errno is `None`. I expected it to be 4.

Is there a better way to catch this error in Python 2.7? I am aware of PEP475, but we cannot upgrade to Python 3 right now.

Comment: Which python 2 exactly? `socket.error`s were changed to subclass `IOError` at some point causing havoc on argument passing and resulting attribute values of the error.

Comment: We are using Python 2.7

Comment: This might be it https://bugs.python.org/issue6471, or at least related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<urlopen error [Errno 4] Interrupted system call>` indicates it is actually a `URLError` from [`urllib2`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/urllib2.py), which subclasses `IOError`, but handles arguments completely differently. That is why the attributes `errno` and `strerror` are not initialized. It both passes strings as reason:

```
        raise URLError("qop '%s' is not supported." % qop)
```

and wraps exceptions from other sources:

```
    try:
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
    except socket.error, err: # XXX what error?
        h.close()
        raise URLError(err)
```

This is why you will not find *errno* in the usual place:

```
>>> try:                      
    urlopen('http://asdf')
except URLError, e:
    pass
... 
>>> e
URLError(gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'),)
>>> e.errno
>>> e.reason
gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')
>>> e.reason.errno
-2
```

This worked in this case, but the *reason* attribute could be a string or a `socket.error`, which [has (had) its own problems with *errno*](https://bugs.python.org/issue6471).

The definition of `URLError` in *urllib2.py*:

```
class URLError(IOError):
    # URLError is a sub-type of IOError, but it doesn't share any of
    # the implementation.  need to override __init__ and __str__.
    # It sets self.args for compatibility with other EnvironmentError
    # subclasses, but args doesn't have the typical format with errno in
    # slot 0 and strerror in slot 1.  This may be better than nothing.
    def __init__(self, reason):
        self.args = reason,
        self.reason = reason

    def __str__(self):
        return '<urlopen error %s>' % self.reason
```

So long story short, it's a horrible mess. You have to check `e.reason` for

1. Is it just a string? If so, there'll be no *errno* anywhere.
2. Is it a `socket.error`? Handle quirks of that. Again the *errno* attribute can be unset, or `None`, since it could also be raised with a [single string argument](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4205).
3. Is it a subclass of `IOError` or `OSError` (which subclass [`EnvironmentError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError))? Read *errno* attribute of that – and hope for the best.

This can be and probably is overly cautious for your case, but it is good to understand the edges. [Tornado had similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048580/tornado-interrupted-system-call) and is using a [utility function to get errno from exception](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/util.py#L163), but unfortunately that function does not work with *URLErrors*.

What could cover at least some cases:

```
while True:  # or some amount of retries
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=30)
        break
    except URLError, e:
        if getattr(e.reason, 'errno', None) == errno.EINTR:
            # Retry
            continue
```

Comment: I looked at the source for `URLError` but didn't realize it was required that I would need to check for that error first. I'll give that a try. It may take a while to verify since I'm still not sure if it's actually the website that is causing the error to be thrown.

Comment: Your code is a lot more succinct than ours, but pretty much the same. We just have a lot of logging added. If this approach works, I'll look into refactoring it down a bit so it's a little clearer